# How to hide list when there is no component present in list in ireport

Tags: jasper-reports

In my report I have a list component which can be empty, so when there is no value in it I would like to hide it completely instead of having a blank space, so the next component (float position) could go up. When I use `isRemoveLineWhenBlank=true` next component go up but empty (that I want) but empty space will remain at the end of frame. Can I eliminate this?

Comment: Need to see your jrxml, probably you have other components that do not have float position or the band height is not correct...

Comment: Remeber to add you jrxml use the edit button under the question